# Change Liberica Jdk with another one in spring-boot:build-image

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin, paketo

i've read that is possible to change default buildpack Liberica Jdk with another one, but i can't find any example or documentation about this.
Can someone help me,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Use spring-boot-2.5.x (not in GA right now) and buildpacks configuration feature to customize buildpacks

Comment: More background on how this works: https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/language-family-buildpacks/java/#using-alternative-jvms (explains how to do this with `pack` but works the same for Maven config in Spring Boot 2.5+). Spring Boot 2.5 preview docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-customization